# WPF Sliding Panel

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to make a control which behaves like Blend menu control:

[image]

As in Image, Clicking on Assets, A menu would slide out and menu other window side to it would shrink and make space for new sliding menu to reside there. The menu should reside there until any action is performed to slide it back in. (Like I would put a button at same place Cancel button(x) in image ).

Also should not be like a dock panel to another place as we do with Toolbox with VS on Blend.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I found some code on web, they are for dockable panel, but they dont work the way I want.
Also I want to make Some simple functionality to achieve it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at MahApps Metro and its Flyout control. I think it's close to what you are looking for. http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Answer (score 6):

I created a window to show you how you can achieve your goal. It has 2 buttons on the right-above side of the window, and if you click on each of them, a red or a black border will be expanded.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUpper.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationUpper" Height="100" Width="200">

<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Border Name="ContentBorder"
                Width="0">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder"
                        Property="Width"
                        Value="Auto" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Name="B1" Content="T" Click="B1_Click"/>
        <Button Name="B2"
                Content="F" Click="B2_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Expander Name="MainExpander1"
                      Template="{StaticResource VerticalExpander}"
                      IsExpanded="False">
                <Border Background="Black"
                        Width="50">
                </Border>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Name="MainExpander2"
                      Template="{StaticResource VerticalExpander}"
                      IsExpanded="False"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Border Background="Red"
                        Width="50">
                </Border>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
        <Border Name="NonSliding"
                Width="100"
                Height="50"
                Background="Green">

        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and in code behind:

```
    private void B1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            MainExpander1.IsExpanded = !MainExpander1.IsExpanded;
    }

    private void B2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainExpander2.IsExpanded = !MainExpander2.IsExpanded;
    }
```

Comment: MainExpander1.IsExpanded = !MainExpander1.IsExpanded;